# How do I know if a thread stopped in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I take a test to make a progress bar for simulating a download. Start the download when the ProgressBar showed.

```
void CProgressBarTest::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
...
    auto funDownloadCallback = [&](int i)->int {
        if (m_downloadStopFlag)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        m_progress_bar.SetPos(i);
        return i;
    };
    std::thread thDownload(__HeavyWork::SimulateDownload, funDownloadCallback);
    thDownload.swap(m_thDownload);
}
```

To stop the download when click cancellatio button or close the window.

```
void CProgressBarTest::OnClose()
{
    m_downloadStopFlag = true;
    m_thDownload.join();//How do I know if the thread alread stopped. If the thread stopped, it would crash.
    CDialog::OnClose();
}
```

Here, I use a flag (m_downloadStopFlag) to tell the thread to stop. And use `m_thDownload.join();` to wait for the thread being stopped. It works fine to stop the download.

But, if I wait the download finished (the thread also is finished,) I close this dialog and that would still call `m_thDownload.join();` which lead to crash.

How do I know if the thread finished then I can skip `m_thDownload.join();`?

Comment: AFAIK you can't,you need to add a `bool` (or whatever) to the end of your thread which you can signal completion from. Someone might have something better than this though

Comment: join does not crash if the thread is already finished, but just returns immediately. Accessing the GUI from multiple threads will probably cause issues (depending on GUI framework). Also, identifiers starting with __ are forbidden for user code (__HeavyWork).

Comment: @Erlkoenig, yes, yes. It's not m_thDownload.join(); caused the crash. I'm a donkey. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Your GUI framework probably provides some kind of timer class. Use that for your progress simulation. Needlessly using threads just calls for trouble!

Comment: This `thDownload.swap(m_thDownload);` looks dangerous. The thread that was in was in `m_thDownload` will throw an exception on exit as `thDownload` goes out of scope. If you know `m_thDownload` isn't running you can get the same behaviour from assignment: `m_thDownload = std::thread (__HeavyWork::SimulateDownload, funDownloadCallback);` Agree with @Erlkoenig . Every GUI framework I've worked with has support for event-based programming. Look into using it rather than threads. Manipulating a GUI from multiple threads quickly becomes a synchronization nightmare.

Comment: `joinable`??? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable

Comment: @Brandon, Yes, joinable works. Unexpectedly, that's so simple.

Comment: @Brandon write an answer

Comment: I don't think it works. What if the thread terminates between the call to `joinable` and the call to `join`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, doesn't matter as long as you don't call `join` multiple times, `join` throws when a thread has already been joined not when the thread has terminated

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's not consistent with the problem description. The problem description seems to be stating that joining a thread that's terminated causes his program to crash. If that's the issue, this isn't a fix. If that's not the issue, then there's no reason to think this is a fix either.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz his issue is that `onClose` and his button click handler aare both calling `join` which will cause an exception

Comment: @Zhang please don't edit your question to include the answer its very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` doesn't throw an exception if the thread has already completed, it only throws when `join` has already been called or the thread has never been started, you can detect these conditions with [`joinable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable). The following should never throw an exception from `join`:

```
if (thread.joinable())
{
  thread.join();
}
```

Comment: `thread::join()` also throws an exception if the thread has been detached.